# Creating clickable linearlayout dynamically

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have to create LinearLayouts dinamically according to an Entity List. The Layouts are drawn without problems. My problem is when I try to know which Layout I have clicked, because always is referencing the last.

The code is something like this:

```
LinearLayout llProducts = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.llProducts);
LinearLayout llNewProduct;
int i = 0;

foreach(Product p in productsList)
{

     llNewProduct = new LinearLayout(this);
     llNewProduct.Clickable = true;
     llNewProduct.Id = i++;

     TextView txtProduct = new TextView(this);
     txtProduct.Text = p.Name;

     llNewProduct.AddView(txtProduct);
     llProducts.AddView(llNewProduct);

     llNewProduct.Click += (sender, e)
     {
         //This always shows the last Id
         Toast.MakeText(this, llNewProduct.Id.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }

}
```

I appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: where does it come from `llNewProduct.Clickable = true;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said on the last comment. The question is solved. Next code shows the id from layout clicked.

```
llNewProduct.Click += (sender, e) 
{ 
     LinearLayout ll = sender as LinearLayout; 
     Toast.MakeText(this, ll.Id.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Array of boolean sucg as `boolean[] flag = new boolean[productList.length]`. After this, you can set flag[i] = true when you set llNewProduct.Clickable = true; other set flag[i] =false;
After completion for each loop you can find out clicked lineanlayout with the help of this flag such as

```
for(int i=0;i<flag.length;i++){ 
if(flag[i]){
Log.v("TAG","Clicked linear layout");
}else{
Log.v("TAG","Not Clicked linear layout");
}
}
```

Use following code in foor loop

```
llNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(YouActivity.this, ""+v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't want to know which layout is clickable. All are clickable. I need to know, for example, the product name contained in layout. And when I click in any layout, always I get the last product name

Comment: You can use llNewProduct.setTag(i) and when you click on the linearlayout then you can get it from getTag() and it will give you the value of i. Whenever you get the position from i you can get the product name value from productList.get(i).getProductName(). If u still have a problem please let me know.

Comment: Doing that I have the same problem. The tag returned is the last for every layout clicked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I solved doing this:

     llNewProduct.Click += (sender, e)
     {
         LinearLayout ll = sender as LinearLayout;
         Toast.MakeText(this, ll.Id.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
     }

Answer (score 0):

you are using same reference for all added view, create different views in side loop
 Try like this:

```
for(int i1 = 0; i1 < 3;i1++)
    {

         LinearLayout llNewProduct = new LinearLayout(this);
         LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(100, 100);
         llNewProduct.setLayoutParams(p);
         if(i1 == 0) llNewProduct.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         if(i1 == 1) llNewProduct.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
         if(i1 == 2) llNewProduct.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
         llNewProduct.setClickable(true);
         llNewProduct.setId(i1);


         llNewProduct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(CaptureImage.this, ""+v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
         ll1.addView(llNewProduct);
    }
```